# How do i get analytic reports from YouTube API for CMS account?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

Basically, i want to get analytic reports through YouTube API by using Python. After hours searching how to make it happend. I am known that YouTube just supporting API through their graphical design, which is really limited. 
Please advised me, is there any way to get daily/weekly/monthly report by using Python?
FYI, at the moment, i am using YouTube's service to automatically update the reports into my database which is BigTable.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita Do you understand the question? There is no code here. This is a discussion.

Comment: @PhucTrinh If you are looking for a discussion you are in the wrong place; discussions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Could you share more of your research? Do you already get reports by other means? What kind of reports?

Comment: @ModusTollens I have tried many ways. Basically, i want to get daily report from YouTube such as Revenue, Views with some filters like video_id, channel_id etc. But what i can get til now is YouTube graphical API which is very limited. I cannot get the reports like above.